# Looking for a Writing Time Tracker

Tags: creative-writing, software, resources, wordcount

I'm looking for something simple to track time, not words. Last year's goal was 500 words a day. This year's goal is 30 minutes a day. Leaves me more flexibility to edit and plan rather than solely focus on pumping out words. A simple Excel sheet will work just fine.

Comment: Writing softwares, such as Scrivener, allow to set up daily targets.

Comment: Are you looking for an automated solution, or just an Excel sheet w/ rows and columns?

Comment: Hi Apples, and welcome. I'm sorry, but I just don't think this is constrained enough for our format. As asked, it seems like anything from a good old stopwatch to a super-high-tech solution integrated into the computer's keyboard controller could be an answer to this question, and there's very little to judge how well any given answer actually answers this. If you can [Edit] your question to clearly lay out a list of requirements, it might work better.

Comment: Also, if "a simple Excel sheet will work just fine", then what's preventing you from going that route? Tell us what you really *need*, and we might be able to help you out. I've put this on hold for the moment to keep from people wasting their time answering the wrong question, but with any luck, with some editing we'll be able to reopen this and get you the answer you need. If you edit during the "on hold" grace period, your question will automatically be entered into the review queues for our experienced community members to look at.